# Iterate over COM collection without foreach or .Item()

Tags: vb.net, matlab, collections, com

I need to iterate over a COM collection within Matlab. In VB I could use `For Each item In Collection`; in Python I could use `for item in Collection`. But unfortunately such constructs are not available in Matlab, which uses a simple loop, something like this:

```matlab
for index = 1 : Collection.Count
   item = Collection.Item(index);
   % now do something useful with the item
end
```

This works well in general. But in my particular Collection, `.Item()` only accepts a string (the item's name), not a numeric index. So the code snippet above fails, because I do not know the item names in advance, before iterating over the loop.

In VB I could do `item = Collection(index)`, but this fails in Matlab, since Matlab understands this as "item is Collection number index". In other words, Collection(2) tries to access the 2nd collection, not the 2nd item within Collection. This is why we typically use `.Item(index)` in Matlab, but as I said above, this fails in my particular collection where `Item` only accepts strings.

So my question is: can I iterate over a COM collection without a `foreach` construct or an `Item(index)` method?

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how to do it in COM, but I have no knowledge if Matlab can do this.

There is a special property `DISPID_NEWENUM`, with the name `_NewEnum`. Retrieving this property gets a IUnknown interface. You can get an interface to an [IEnumVARIANT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221053(v=vs.85).aspx) via `QueryInterface`.

So simply ask for this interface. Then call the [Next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221369(v=vs.85).aspx) method and retrieve VARIANT by VARIANT from your enumeration until the return value is no longer S_OK. Usually S_FALSE is returned when the end of the collection is reached. I always use a count of 1 when I call Next.

So if MatLab can use other interfaces than IDispatch, it should be possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you mind posting a short VB code snippet that implements this? I will then try to convert that VB script to Matlab

Comment: I program only C/C++/C#. But I found documentation on the MATLAB site about using [COM objects](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-com-objects-in-matlab.html)...

Comment: Unfortunately, IEnumVariant is not supported in Matlab, so this looks like a dead end

Comment: Did you checked out, how COM interfaces can be accessed with MATLAB? If you can use IEnumVARIANT you have no chance to access the collection, without knowing the Items.

Comment: yes, I have checked it and it's not supported in Matlab. Matlab issues a warning message about "ActiveX - unsupported VARIANT type encountered" and simply returns a NaN value rather than a COM reference object.

Comment: Than I have no more tips for you.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your time. For reference to anyone else who might stumble on this issue, here's what I did in Matlab:

    >> get(m_CEL.Orders,'_NewEnum')
    Warning: ActiveX - unsupported VARIANT type encountered
    (Type "warning off MATLAB:COM:unsupportedVARIANTtype" to 
    suppress this warning.)
 
    ans =
       NaN

Comment: @Yair Very recently I ran into the missing `VARIANT` type problem. Perhaps you can use a small python wrapper to interface with the COM object, see [this](https://github.com/vskrachkov/sw2014/blob/master/samples/create_part.py#L36) example. Basically you need to create a `.py` file with the contents `import win32com.client \n import pythoncom`, then in MATLAB `cp = py.importlib.import_module('py_filename_w/o_ext'); cp.win32com.client.VARIANT(cp.pythoncom.VT_DISPATCH, py.None);`. I didn't develop it further, but it just might work...